# Undefined Python references in C++ using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, cython, clion

I am trying to compile a c++ project referencing Python using CMake.  I am using Cygwin and I have Python2.7 source files in Cygwin.

For example:

```
PyObject *l = PyList_New(0);
```

Online help suggested I add the -lpython2.7 linker flag.  Am I not adding this correctly in CMake?  Otherwise why can I still not use the Python library and how might I fix this?

The compile line:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\cmake.exe --build "C:\Users\...\.clion10\system\cmake\generated\3e6845d6\3e6845d6\Release" --target projectname -- -j 4
```

The CMakeList.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(projectname)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lpython2.7")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    src/cpp/...
    src/cpp/...
    src/cpp/..
    src/cpp/...
    src/cpp/...)

add_executable(projectname ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

The errors...

```
CMakeFiles/spot.dir/src/cpp/OBwrapper.cpp.o:OBwrapper.cpp:(.text+0xaeb4): undefined reference to `PyDict_New'
CMakeFiles/spot.dir/src/cpp/OBwrapper.cpp.o:OBwrapper.cpp:(.text+0xaeb4): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyDict_New'
CMakeFiles/spot.dir/src/cpp/OBwrapper.cpp.o:OBwrapper.cpp:(.text+0xaec4): undefined reference to `PyList_New'
CMakeFiles/spot.dir/src/cpp/OBwrapper.cpp.o:OBwrapper.cpp:(.text+0xaec4): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyList_New'
CMakeFiles/spot.dir/src/cpp/OBwrapper.cpp.o:OBwrapper.cpp:(.text+0xaf0d): undefined reference to `PyDict_New'
CMakeFiles/spot.dir/src/cpp/OBwrapper.cpp.o:OBwrapper.cpp:(.text+0xaf0d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyDict_New'
CMakeFiles/spot.dir/src/cpp/OBwrapper.cpp.o:OBwrapper.cpp:(.text+0xaf25): undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'

...and so on....
```

Comment: Can you show the compile line

Comment: Updated with the compile line.

Comment: Don't you see a line containing -lpython2.7 ?

Comment: There is no line containing -lpython2.7 or any other library flags that I use, but I know that they are there (stdlib works and setting the flags to something that I don't have throws an error).  I'm using CMake by the way with CLion.

Comment: CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS are used when compiling, you need to add -lpython2.7 to linker flags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand CMake's way: before use something you ought to *find* it! I.e. make sure that everything you need to build your package is available and usable at build host. Otherwise that would be not good to waste a (compile) time (say 2 hours) and then get an error that some header/library/executable not found. So, at CMake run time you'd better to be sure that everything you need is here. To do so, CMake have a lot of tools.

Consider your particular case: you need to find Python libraries otherwise build is not possible. To do so, you ought to use `find_package` like this:

```
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
```

Take a look to [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) and provide other options (like version) if you need. You *shouldn't use* hardcoded paths in your `CMakeLists.txt`, otherwise your project wouldn't be really portable (and most probably you'll be the only who can build it w/o a lot of problems). Instead Python libs finder module will provide variables you need to use later, or failed w/ error if nothing has found.

If CMake ends w/o errors, you may use found Python libs. First of all you need to update `#include` paths:

```
 include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Then tell to linker that your executable `projectname` needs to be linked w/ Python libs:

```
add_executable(projectname ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(projectname ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

And again, try to avoid to modify `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` (and others) directly -- there are bunch of calls to do that globally and/or per target. Some of them are:

- [`add_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html) to define/undefine macros
- [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) to update `#include` paths
- [`add_compile_options`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_compile_options.html) to add other compiler options
- [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html) to update linker search paths

Comment: This worked, thank you!  One small modification, for find_packages the flag should be "REQUIRED" and not "REQUIRE".

Comment: On CLion, all lines that have: `PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pClass, *pInstance=NULL;` I get for pName (for example) the text is in red color and the mouse over tip is "can't resolve variable 'pName'; but  compiles. Any idea I might be missing in the `CMakeLists.txt`?